# How to call a public function from another form

Tags: vb.net, forms, function, call, public

`Frm1` contains the code for validation of `textbox`:

```
Public Function AlphabeticalOnly(ByVal Str As String) As Boolean
    Dim pattern As String = "^[a-zA-Z\s]+$"
    Dim reg As New Regex(pattern)
    If reg.IsMatch(Str) = False Then
        MsgBox(Str & " is invalid! Please enter alphabetical characters only!", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Error")
    End If
    Return reg.IsMatch(Str)
End Function
```

Because there're quite an amount of validations, I don't want to repeat all the code again in the other forms.

```
Private Sub btnDone_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnDone.Click
If AlphabeticalOnly(txtName.Text) = False Then
        Exit Sub
End If
...
End Sub
```

I tried the code above in another form, but the error list shows that `AlphabeticalOnly` is not declared.

Is there anything that I need to add to my code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, don't put the function on a *form*.  If it's common code shared by all forms, put it in its own class file.

Second, this common code shouldn't be prompting the user with a message box.  This function *should* just perform the logic and nothing more.  (This also makes the function easier to unit test.)  Then allow the consuming code (in this case a form) to interact with the user.  (Especially since the current implementation checks the match twice, which isn't necessary.)

Since this function doesn't rely on object state, you can make it `Shared`.  Something like this:

```
Public Class CommonFunctions
    Public Shared Function IsAlphabeticalOnly(ByVal Str As String) As Boolean
        Dim pattern As String = "^[a-zA-Z\s]+$"
        Dim reg As New Regex(pattern)
        Return reg.IsMatch(Str)
    End Function
End Class
```

Then on your forms you can invoke that function:

```
If CommonFunctions.IsAlphabeticalOnly(txtName.Text) = False Then
    MsgBox(Str & " is invalid! Please enter alphabetical characters only!", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Error")
End If
```

Comment: I would caution against excessive use of static functions, as they make unit testing more difficult by becoming something that cannot be faked out. Otherwise your answer was spot on, and I have no clue who down voted it.

Comment: Hi David! Your method worked like a charm! However, I figured out that using KeyPress event for each text box is a better way in my case! Thanks anyway!

Comment: @Caesium95: Glad I could help!  The keypress event is just as good, the main point here isn't which event to use but rather where to organize common code.  This sort of helper method definitely belongs in a UI-level helper class rather than on a form.  It's debatable whether it should be `Shared` or not, or what the structure of that common code should be.  Ideally this would move to a more object-oriented design as more code is added.  But for just this one helper method the goal is to get in the practice of simply moving the code off of a form.